# JavaScript Object Creation and its Prototype

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

I create an Object in JavaScript:

```
var object = {value1 : "value1", value2 : "value2"};
```

If I now try and count the contents of 'object.prototype' I get the result 0. If I add properties I get the correct result. Am I to take it then that 'object.prototype' is in fact empty?

Thanks!

Comment: In your example I find `object.prototype` is `undefined`, and you can't count contents of `undefined`. There is an `object.constructor` (which in Chrome is `function Object() { [native code] }`, and you _can_ check `Object.prototype`).

Comment: thanks, could you show me what you did?

Comment: I just pasted your line of code into Chrome's console, then after that I evaluated `object.prototype`, `object.constructor` and `Object.prototype`. Note that you _can_ add properties to `Object.prototype`, but you _shouldn't_ do so.

Comment: I have never used Chrome console before...will give it a go...

Comment: There is internal `__proto__` in every object .. but its not a valid part of JavaScript, some browsers still has this property. for checking working of this try this .`Object.prototype.a = 'value a in native Object' ;` and print `object.__proto__.a` . this link has more info http://sporto.github.io/blog/2013/02/22/a-plain-english-guide-to-javascript-prototypes/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Javascript, by DEFAULT only "function objects" have a prototype property..

for example, none of the following have a prototype property by default -

```
var a = new Object();
var b = {};
var a = new Array();
var b = [];
```

But,

```
var a = function() {};
```

has a prototype property.. and by default -

```
a.prototype is {constructor : this}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate through all the properties you assigned to your object, you can just do it with a for..in loop:

```
for (var prop in object){
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
        var propValue = object[prop];
        // ...
    }
}
```

If you need to count the properties, you can just increment a counter on each iteration.